# $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4 \simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ true or false?

Tags: group-theory

**True or false exercise**

> Is $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ ?

Acording to the **Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups**:

$\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

$\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

Therefore  $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_8$

However the solution claims the statement to be false.

According to ***John Hughes*** comment:

> **Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups**:If $G$ is an finitely generated abelian so that $G\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{n_1}}\times...\mathbb{Z}_{{p_k}^{n_k}}\times \mathbb{Z}^n$ or $G\simeq\mathbb{Z}^n$
>
> where $p_1,...,p_k$ are prime and not necessarily distinct, $n_1,...,n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n>0$.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong? Is the solution wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the order of each element in each of those two groups? For instance, what's the order of $(1, 1)$ in the first, and of $(0, 1)$ in the second one? Do this for every $(a, b)$ in each group. It won't take long, and it'll be instructive.

Comment: Also: you're apparently misreading the theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. Perhaps you could write whatever version you're using here, and we can show you in what way you're misunderstanding it.

Comment: @JohnHughes Please Check my edit!

Comment: @JohnHughes Could you point out what did I do wrong with the decomposition of the given groups?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_4 = \Bbb Z_{2^2} \times \Bbb Z_{2^2}$, so $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_4$ is already in the form guaranteed by the theorem ($p_1 = p_2 = 2; n_1 = n_2 = 2$), so you can't just say that it has to be equal to some other form that also satisfies the theorem! Otherwise, you could say it's just $\Bbb Z_{13} \times \Bbb Z_{19} \times \Bbb Z^3$. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already make an implicit mistake when replacing $\mathbb Z_4$ with $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$. Those two groups are not isomorphic, they just have the same number of elements.

It is true that $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z_q $ is isomorphic with $\mathbb Z_{pq} $ *if $p $ and $q $ are coprime* (Chinese remainder theorem), but obviously 2 isn't coprime with 2.

Comment: Please check my edit!

Comment: I think you may still have mistyped the theorem. It should say $\mathbb Z_{p_1^{n_1}}\times\ldots\times\mathbb Z_{p_k^{n_k}}\times \mathbb Z^n $, i.e. the orders of the finite cyclic groups are *powers* of primes - not necessarily primes. (That is why they say that the primes may not all be mutually different.)

Comment: Actually, the theorem is often stated in a bit stronger form: up to the order of the cyclic group, this representation is unique! From there, it directly follows that $\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_8$. I don't know if you've seen this stronger statement already, or is this exercise some sort of introduction to it...

Comment: (sorry, meant to say "up to the *ordering* of the cyclic groups...")

Comment: Teacher did not provide a proof of this theorem nor the book has one. I have been looking for proofs on the internet but the statements ,I found of the theorem, are not specifically this one, with the $\mathbb{Z}_n$. I am not understanding when and how I can make  use  of  this result. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Could you point out what did I do wrong with the decomposition of the given groups?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_4=\mathbb Z_{2^2}\times \mathbb Z_{2^2}$ is already decomposed. Nothing in the theorem guarantees you that you can either decompose it *further* or decompose it *differently*.

Answer (score 2):

Every element of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times{}\mathbb{Z}_2\times{}\mathbb{Z}_2\times{}\mathbb{Z}_2$ has order 2, but this is not true for $\mathbb{Z}_4\times{}\mathbb{Z}_4$. So the two groups aren't isomorphic.

Comment: Please check my edit!

Answer (score 1):

I think you make confusion between

**1)** Every abelian group of order $16$ is isomorphic to one of the following group : $$\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2,\quad \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_8 ,\quad \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_4,\quad \mathbb Z_{16},$$

*and*

**2)** All abelian group of order 16 are isomorphic.

The last proposition is of course wrong, and it's the first one that is true. As you can see, none of groups of **1)** can be isomorphic since for example $\mathbb Z_{16}$ has an element of order $16$, whereas $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_8$ has none element of order $16$.

Comment: Could you point out what did I do wrong with the decomposition of the given groups?

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you state is simply wrong - $\mathbb Z_4$ is a counterexample. In the correct version of the theorem $p_j$ is not required to be prime, it is just a power of a prime.

Comment: Could you point out what did I do wrong with the decomposition of the given groups?

Comment: @PedroGomes I thought I did point that out. Your application of the "theorem" was correct. But the "theorem" you're using is simply _wrong_ - if you correctly apply a false "theorem" you're going to get false results.

Comment: I guess I have corrected the theorem in one of my last updates. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @PedroGomes ??? The version of the theorem I see here still says $p_j$ is prime. Wrong. False. Untrue, incorrect.

Comment: It is the one the teacher provided me.

Comment: @PedroGomes Ok, the theorem is now correct - for some reason the latest edit took a long time to appear. Now the correct version of the theorem simply doesn't imply that $\mathbb Z_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$.